# Query grouping by association column value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm in a situation where I've got a set of garages that need to be grouped and sorted by a relational value. The associations look like this

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :garages
end

class Garage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
end
```

In the situation I'm in I've got an activerecord collection that needs to be grouped and sorted by the group name, which is at `group.name`.

At this moment I'm going like this, but this lacks sorting of groups and I only really need the name value, not the whole group.

```
@garage_groups = current_user.garages.group_by(&:group)
```

It would be awesome if I could just set `.group_by(&:group.name)` but obviously that's not going to work.

I should probably add that some garages lack a group and will be grouped with a nil key in the `@garage_groups` hash.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `JOIN` and `GROUP (not group_by)` together. In that, you can use like `group("group.name")`.

Comment: @sajan if I go `.joins(:group).group("group.name")` instead of `.group_by(&:group)` I get a StatementInvalid error:
`PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "group"
LINE 1: ... ON "groups"."id" = "garages"."group_id" GROUP BY group.name...`.

This is the SQL it returns: `SELECT "garages".* FROM "garages" INNER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."id" = "garages"."group_id" GROUP BY group.name ORDER BY LOWER(name)`

Comment: I guess, that will be `"groups.name"` since table name is plural "groups" . I am getting a little confused because of groups table name since that is similar to GROUP keyword.

Comment: @sagan is right, you need to do `.joins(:group).group("groups.name")` it's slightly counter-intuitive because `joins` uses the relation name but `group` uses the table name.